# java script regex .match find only one result

Tags: javascript, regex, html-parsing

i have this js code :

```
result = subject.match(/<a.*class="gallery_browser_thumbnail".*href="(.+)">/i);
```

i want to get href of multiple a tags on a html source
but it shows only 1 result

if i use /g at end of pattern it returns whole patterns but i just want only the href part
i mean -> (.+)  this part

this is how i capture html input :

```
var subject = String(document
.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML);
```

any help?

final working script :

```
    var subject = String(document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML);
var regex = /<a.*class="gallery_browser_thumbnail".*href="(.+)">/gi;
var matched = null;
while (matched = regex.exec(subject)) {
  alert(matched[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to lazy match by adding the lazy quantifier `?`:

```
result = subject.match(/<a.*?class="gallery_browser_thumbnail".*?href="(.+?)">/i);
```

Comment: i got this : ["<a class="gallery_brows...duct/d/s/dsc_0464.jpg">", "<a class="gallery_brows...duct/d/s/dsc_0464.jpg">", "<a class="gallery_browser_thumbnail" href="", "media/catalog/product/d/s/dsc_0464.jpg"]

Comment: but i want this : ["media/catalog/product/d/s/dsc_0464.jpg" , "media/catalog/product/d/s/dsc_0464.jpg", "media/catalog/product/d/s/dsc_0464.jpg"] ...]

Comment: i need global matches + only href part

Answer (score 0):

You can use exec to test RegExp. Something like this:

```
var subject = String(document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML),
    regexp = /<a.*class="gallery_browser_thumbnail".*href="(.+)">/gi, //g for global match
    match = regexp.exec(subject),
    result = [];
while(match != null){
    result.push(match[1]); // the second value is matched group
    match = regexp.exec(subject);
}
```

Comment: your code is not working with error : TypeError: match is null

Comment: @SinaMiandashti, you're right. Swap it with line 6. I've modified the answer.